# PHP $_GET array nested parameters not working

Tags: php, arrays, apache, parameters

I'm experiencing strange behaviour on a debian server with LAMP-Stack.

This simple test explains my problem:
This is my test.php script:

```
<?php
  $params = $_GET;
  print_r($params);
?>
```

If I issue the url: `http://localhost/test.php?arr[a]=1&arr[b]=2&arr[c]=3&test=xyz`
I would expect the server to return:

```
    
Array
(
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
        )
    [test] => xyz
)
```

But I only get:

```
Array
(
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
        )
    [test] => xyz
)
```

I checked the php.ini, apache config and so one. I don't have a clou why the parameters are not processed correctly.
Even my

```
$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

variable shows the correct parameters, but they are simply not processed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to encode the URI ? If i'm not wrong '[' and ']' would be encoded by the browser if they were sent via a form post.

Comment: Did you try replacing `&` with `&amp;`?

Comment: There was a bug in `parse_str` in some PHP versions, if I recall correctly. I've seen this question here before...

Comment: This could fix your $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] problem. http://davidwalsh.name/iis-php-server-request_uri

Comment: One suggestion to overcome this problem is : 
implode the array,urlencode it and pass it to URL

Comment: The problem is neither encoding, nor anything related to php. I have about 25 servers and on every server there can be arrays in GET-parameters. Only this particular server is behaving different, which causes a lot of php-portals not to work, because they often use this functionality. This is a special case and not a programming issue, but HTTP-Standard. It's simply not working and I can't figure out why.

Comment: This is the phpinfo (anonymized): [http://pastehtml.com/view/cg9yk4o4q.html](http://pastehtml.com/view/cg9yk4o4q.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured the problem out:

**This is a bug in PHP 5.3.8 on SUSE Enterprise Linux**. 
I got the admin to upgrade to PHP 5.3.17 and this misbehavior disappeared.

Comment: It would be more specific if you could provide a link to the bug ticket in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something wrong:

When I call `www.mysite.com/test.php?arr[a]=1&arr[b]=2&arr[c]=3&test=xyz`

and do a `print_r($_GET);`

I get

```
Array ( [arr] => Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 ) [test] => xyz )
```

**Update**

output from var_dump:

```
array(2) { 
  ["arr"]=> array(3) { ["a"]=> string(1) "1" ["b"]=> string(1) "2" ["c"]=> string(1) "3" }
  ["test"]=> string(3) "xyz" 
}
```

Comment: I think he know's something is wrong.  That's the point here.  This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I agree with JvdBerg. Works on mine as well.

Comment: Getting the same output with PHP 5.3.8, though I somewhat agree with @RocketHazmat

Comment: Based on the given information I think this is the answer to the question. I have not problem deleting my answer if more information is provided and the question changes.